Execute multiple commands against a specific file if found in a directory recusively
I have 2 directories paul & matt with some subfolders within each which potentially contains (or will contain) a kustomization.yaml file. What I am trying to do is to run multiple commands in the path where a kustomization.yaml is found in paul/* and matt/*. So if I was to do this manually:
cd paul
somecommand1 kustomization.yaml
somecommand2 kustomization.yaml
cd paul/test
somecommand1 kustomization.yaml
somecommand2 kustomization.yaml
cd paul/test/test1
somecommand1 kustomization.yaml
somecommand2 kustomization.yaml
---
cd matt
somecommand1 kustomization.yaml
somecommand2 kustomization.yaml
cd matt/test
somecommand1 kustomization.yaml
somecommand2 kustomization.yaml
cd matt/test/test1
somecommand1 kustomization.yaml
somecommand2 kustomization.yaml

I am still learning bash but I know that a Bash script I can call on my GitLab pipeline with some steps that will do something like a loop to find any kustomization.yaml in those 2 directories recursively, then run x, y, and z against any found kustomization.yaml file will do the job.

You can use find paul matt -type d -exec /path/to/script {} \; to run a script in each directory and subdirectory. The script can check whether the directory contains kustomization.yaml and then run the commands.

You could use find command with multiple use of -exec option like that:
find matt paul -name "kustomization.yaml" \
  -exec echo -n "Work on '{}' file in " \; -exec pwd \; \
  -exec somecommand1 {} \; \
  -exec somecommand2 {} \;

Alternative
Use -execdir option to execute commands in the directory where file found.
find matt paul -name "kustomization.yaml" \
  -execdir echo -n "Work on '{}' file in: " \; -execdir pwd \; \
  -execdir somecommand1 {} \; \
  -execdir somecommand2 {} \;

Alternative 2
Use a subscript: /some/path/my_commands.sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# cd "${1%/*}" # Necessary if you use `-exec` option instead of `-execdir`
echo "Work on '$1' in '$(pwd)' dirrectory"
somecommand1 "$1"
somecommand1 "$1"

chmod +x /some/path/my_commands.sh

And use only one -execdir option:
find matt paul -name "kustomization.yaml" \
  -execdir /some/path/my_commands.sh {} \;

This alternative is very useful if you want to make treatments with return codes from somecommand* executions:
Subscript: /some/path/my_commands.sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# cd "${1%/*}" # Necessary if you use `-exec` option instead of `-execdir`
# It may be important to check the return code of `cd` command before continue
# if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
#   echo "ERR: ${0##*/}: Cannot change directory to '${1%/*}'" >&2
#   exit 1
# fi

echo "Work on '$1' file in '$(pwd)' directory"

if somecommand1 "$1"; then
  ...
else
  ...
fi
...
if somecommand2 "$1"; then
  ...
else
  ...
fi


You might want to use -execdir instead of -exec, which executes the command in the directories where the files are found.

@Arnaud Valmary you are my hero :) GOD BLESS

You may use find command and its -execdir option for this. To run multiple commands with -execdir you would have to repeat the -execdir option for each command which could be a bit clumsy. One way to go around that is using sh -c like this:
find matt paul -type f -name kustomization.yaml -execdir sh -c '    
    echo "Executing in directory $(pwd)"
    somecommand1 {}
    somecommand2 {}
' \;

If you want to store some state between the directories or modify variables in the scope of the script executing the find command, something like this might work:
#!/bin/bash
set -e  # Fail the whole script if any subcommand fail
total=0  # Example of a variable that is modified in the loop
while read -r -d '' dir; do
    pushd "$dir" >/dev/null # Change to the directory
    somecommand1 kustomization.yaml
    somecommand2 kustomization.yaml
    total=$((total+1))
    popd >/dev/null  # Change back to the original directory
done < <(find matt paul -type f -name kustomization.yaml -printf "%h\0")
echo "Total $total directories processed"

That needs Bash whereas the first example should probably work with bare sh so it's more portable.

This is prone to quoting errors where you assume {} will not contain whitespace or wildcard characters. The safe equivalent would be to pass the file name as an explicit argument to sh -c. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020
